# Short story about man taking an exam so he and his wife can have children

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Can't recall the author or date, but I do recall a short story about a man going through an exam -- essay questions, recalling theorems -- and we know it's important and that his wife passed, and that he failed at least once before. only at the end do we find out that only by passing the exam will he be permitted to father a child with his wife. Can anyone help me out with the author or title?  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I vote this a candidate for preventing an idiocracy-style timeline.

Comment: Hmm . . . There's a similar theme in Henry Slesar's "Examination Day" made into a pithy New Twilight Zone episode. A child is tested by the government and his parents are very concerned that he do well enough . . . Their fears are grounded when it turns out the boy exceeds the regulation IQ and is euthanized, at a cost of $10 to the parents for "standard internment of remains".
 Very much a tale of the 70s when being smart was linked to bad technology like space rockets and atom bombs. Bit of a diversion, sorry.

Comment: Brin's "Piecework" has the flip side of this; a woman studying and taking tests until she is finally qualified to be a parent.  I also recall a story where a school principal is studying and studying until he becomes qualified to be a teacher.